# Do C++ compilers eliminate assignment duplications?

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

If I have an example function like:

```
void func1(float a, float b, float c)
{
    setA(a);
    setB(b);
    setC(c);                                        
}
```

Which calls inlined functions:

```
inline void setA(float a){ m_a = a; m_isValid = false; }
inline void setB(float b){ m_b = b; m_isValid = false; }
inline void setC(float c){ m_c = c; m_isValid = false; }
```

Should I care about the "m_isValid = false" duplications or the compiler eliminates them by the optimization?

Comment: I very much doubt it; anyway the time spent with the operation is minimal and probably you are better off letting it as it is instead of "optimizing" it (premature optimization is the root of all evil)

Comment: Also be careful that even though even inlined, the code looks sequential, the value could still be concurrently modified by another thread, making such an optimization a pretty bad thing.

Comment: On the contrary, the compiler will repeat that assignment *many* times.  A function like this will almost always be inlined since it typically only takes two cpu instructions.  It doesn't matter, it makes your code *faster*.

Comment: @SirDarius: No, it couldn't, since there is no synchronization mechanism. (You cannot assume that there is some invisible incorrect code which breaks a perfectly fine example).

Comment: @MSalters well, the answers here indeed demonstrated that the optimization takes place, and doing multi-threaded programming without synchronizing would indeed not make much sense, so my previous comment shouldn't be paid too much attention. I guess access to `m_isValid` from multiple threads would fall under undefined behaviour, right ?

Comment: @SirDarius: Pure read access wouldn't, but since the code above writes to it, all threads have to guard access. (If it was an `atomic` variable, it would be well defined, but there's no indication it is.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A decent compiler should remove them in this specific case.

Completing to a full compiling example

```
struct Foo {
    float m_a, m_b, m_c;
    bool m_isValid;

    void setA(float a){ m_a = a; m_isValid = false; }
    void setB(float b){ m_b = b; m_isValid = false; }
    void setC(float c){ m_c = c; m_isValid = false; }

    void func1(float a, float b, float c);
};

Foo f;

void func1(float a, float b, float c)
{
    f.setA(a);
    f.setB(b);
    f.setC(c);
}
```

g++ in this case compiles `func1` to

```
_Z5func1fff:
.LFB3:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    4(%esp), %eax     ;; loads a
    movb    $0, f+12          ;; clears m_isValid
    movl    %eax, f           ;; stores m_a
    movl    8(%esp), %eax     ;; loads b
    movl    %eax, f+4         ;; stores m_b
    movl    12(%esp), %eax    ;; loads c
    movl    %eax, f+8         ;; stores m_c
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Note that while it's true that you should keep an eye out about how to design a program if performance is an issue, this kind of micro-level optimization is best done at the end, after measuring where the code is actually losing time.

Comment: Any idea how to do this in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate? I can't access the dissassembly window.

Comment: Though this optimization depends on `set[ABC]` being inlined, which in turn requires either that the definition is in the same TU, or that LTO is used.

Comment: What TU and LTO stand for?

Comment: TU = translation unit (the source code after preprocessing), LTO = Link-Time Optimisation (also known as "Whole Program Optimisation" - the compiler output is only half-baked, and the linker does the final optimisation steps, rather than the usual method where the compiler does all the hard work, and the linker just puts all the pieces together). I personally would be very surprised if Visual Studio with high optimisation doesn't do this sort of optimisation - but you can check by asking the compiler to generate a "listing file" with assembler code.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, this is commonly known as [Dead Store Elimination](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#dse-dead-store-elimination) (read = load and write = store in compilers parlance).

In general, any useless operation can be optimized away by the compiler providing it can prove that you (the user) cannot notice it (within the bounds set up by the language).

For Dead Store Elimination in particular it is generally restricted to:

- the body of a single function (however, inlining helps here)
- without intervening calls to opaque functions

Some examples:

```
struct Foo { int a; int b; };

void opaque(Foo& x); // opaque, aka unknown definition

Foo foo() {
    Foo x{1, 2};
    x.a = 3;
    return x; // provably returns {3, 2}
              // thus equivalent to Foo foo() { return {3, 2}; }
}

Foo bar() {
    Foo x{1, 2};
    opaque(x); // may use x.a, so need to leave it at '1' for now
    x.a = 3;
    return x;
}

Foo baz() {
    Foo x{1, 2};
    opaque(x);
    x.a = 1;   // x.a may have been changed, cannot be optimized
    return x;
}
```

Note that whether you store the same value consecutively or not has not importance, as long as the compiler can prove that a variable is not read between two store operations, it can eliminate the first safely.

A special case: by specification in C++, load/store to a `volatile` cannot be optimized. This is so because `volatile` was specified to allow interactions with the hardware, and thus the compiler cannot know a priori whether the hardware will read or write to the variable behind the program's back.

Another special case: for the purpose of optimizations, memory synchronization operations (fences, barriers, etc...) used in multi-threaded programs can also prevent this kind of optimizations. This is because, pretty much like in the `volatile` case, the synchronization mean that another thread of execution may have modified the variable behind this thread's back.

Finally like all optimizations its effectiveness greatly depends on the knowledge of the context. If it is proven that `opaque` either does not read or does not write to `x.a`, then some stores may be optimized out (provable if the compiler can inspect the definition of `opaque`), so in general it really depends on inlining and constant propagation.

Answer (score 0):

Most of modern compilers (with enabled optimization option) should make it!